# Keep getting "Too many open files" when running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Every so often when I run my RSpec tests (perhaps 1-3 times per day) I get the following error message:

```
Errno::EMFILE:
  Too many open files - socket(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9523
```

If I run `rm -rf tmp/*` it usually fixes the problem for a while but then it comes back.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It might happen if your application opens a lot of files and doesn't close them. There are a limited amount of file descriptors: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`.
Close open files when you don't need them or remove them automatically after each test run:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

config.after(:suite) do # or :each or :all
 Dir["#{Rails.root}/tmp/**/*"].each do |file|
   File.delete(file)
 end
end
```